# Integrate with MS Excel like TFS Workitems

Tags: excel, tfs, integration

Can someone provide me some pointers, articles, best approach, technology choices to build a MS Excel 2010 integration like TFS does for its work items? So as to be able to modify data and republish to a service easily from within Excel.

Greetings and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the MS Workbook with codebehind approach succesfully.